# Console output by extension method that returns IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

When the following code is executed, `ForEach2` outputs to the console, but there is no output by `ForEach`. I was surprised that I thought they would have the same result. Is this a specification, or is something wrong in our environment? What are the specifications, if any?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            Console.WriteLine("ForEach:");
            array.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
            Console.WriteLine("ForEach2:");
            array.ForEach2(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    static class Extension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (var item in target)
            {
                action(item);
                yield return item;
            }
        }

        public static void ForEach2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (var item in target)
            {
                action(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint, it doesn't seem to get into `ForEach` in the first place. I tried to suppress optimization with `[MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]` but the result was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `yield` statement in the `ForEach` method means the method will not be executed until you iterate over the items in the `IEnumerable<T>` returned by `ForEach`. You can see this is true by putting a breakpoint on the `action(item);` line in your code - the breakpoint is not hit.

If you want the code to execute you will need to add a `foreach` for the values returned from `ForEach`. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    Console.WriteLine("ForEach:");
    array.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));

    // add this line
    foreach (var b in array.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a))) { }

    Console.WriteLine("ForEach2:");
    array.ForEach2(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The new line will cause the `ForEach` to execute and yield each result. This will cause the `action(item)` to execute and print the result to the console.

The remarks in the [yield docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield#remarks) tell you that you need to use `foreach` or `LINQ` to consume the results of a `yield` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined a generator method, but since you haven't enumerated the results, nothing happens. Which do you want, the callback or the enumerator?

```cs
        public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target)
        {
            foreach (var item in target)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("ForEach:");
        foreach (var item in array.ForEach())
            Console.WriteLine(item);
```